# webbrowser detect link click and open in new window vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, click, window, detect

I currently am having a problem having a new window open when a link is clinked in my webbrowser, I cannot use webbrowser.Navigating because there are several navigations already occurring before a user can get to the link to open the new window.  I've already looked at [vb.net Detect if a link is clicked in Webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225616/vb-net-detect-if-a-link-is-clicked-in-webbrowser-control) but that didn't help very much.  Is there a way to detect a linkclick in a webbrowser?  I'm at a loss right now an will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do it, the code is below for anyone that has a similar problem.

```
Private Sub webMailNavigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles webMail.Navigating

    ' opens link in new tab if it isn't blank and will not open emails in a new tab.
    Try
        If Not e.Url.ToString.Contains("emailUrl") And Not e.Url.ToString.Contains("about:blank") Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Process.Start(e.Url.ToString)

        Else

        End If

    Catch

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828146/how-to-capture-button-click-event-of-webpage-opened-inside-webbrowser-control) link, which in turn was linked from [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933979/how-to-capture-click-event-for-any-button-inside-in-web-browser-control) post.
Both of which are using C#, however, you can convert it [here](http://converter.telerik.com) if it fits your needs.

Essentially adding an event to the WebBrowser Document.

However, if you do this, it can be fussy. At times it can trigger twice if not coded perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, you were very helpful, but not quite the answer I was looking for, I will post my answer for others to see shortly

Comment: @jdwee You're welcome, and now i see what you'd done in your answer post and understand what you initially going for :) Glad you figured it out